# Converting file_get_contents to an array for IP details

Tags: php, arrays, ip, file-get-contents

I have this simple code on my site:

```
$info = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

which displays like this:

```
{"ip":"123.123.12.1","country_code":"GB","country_name":"United Kingdom","region_code":"ENG","region_name":"England","city":"London","zip_code":"LN1","time_zone":"Europe/London","latitude":30.302,"longitude":-1.123,"metro_code":0}
```

I am trying to turn this in to an array so that I can import this data to the database using something similar to:

```
$ip_address = $info['ip'];
$city = $info['city'];
```

And so on... I have attempted to use `$info[1], $info[2]` and it just displays `{ "` each character of text. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a JSON format and you can use the `json_decode()` function to convert it to either object or array.
So you have:

```
    $info = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $info = json_decode($info, true);
```

Then you can use, as you said, the `$info['ip']` and `$info['city']`

Comment: Absolutely perfect, just needed the nudge in the right direction. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode`

```
$info_obj = json_decode($info);
```

Now $info_obj has the info you want, and you can access it this way:

```
$ip_address = $info_obj->ip;
$city = $info_obj->city;
```